# Is this a question correct?

Tags: sentence-choice

A customer noticed that her bill amount increased on a specific month and I would like to ask her about it.

> When did you start noticing extra charges on your bill?
>
> In which month did you start noticing your bill increasing?
>
> What month did you start noticing an increase of the amount of your bill?

Are those previous questions correct? If no, what's the nature way to say them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about the time of a specific event in the past.  The event is "Customer notices the price change" so you could ask

> When did you notice the extra charges on your bill?

or perhaps

> When did you first notice the extra charges?
>
> In which month did you notice the increase in your bill?

If you ask about "start noticing", this suggests that she repeately noticed something. That sounds odd.  "I noticed an increase" suggests that I wasn't looking for an increase, but I saw it anyway.

Comment: But it’s not necessarily a specific event in the past. For example, the OP’s first question seems like a perfectly reasonable response to, “Awhile back, I started noticing some extra charges on my bill,” which is plausible if we are talking about a bill that I receive monthly.

Comment: So perhaps "first notice" would seem more precise.  I think this is better than "start noticing"

Comment: Sure. It really depends on if we think there person might remember a specific timeframe, or just has a vague notion of it.

Comment: @J.R. Actually, yes the customer notices some extra charges on a specific bill and the following bills as well. So can I say "Start noticing?" Is starting the question by "what month" correct? Can I ask using "start to notice" when talking about one month only?

Comment: @user2824371 - You can ask, _“When did you start to notice...?” “When did you start noticing...?” "What month did you first notice...?”_ All of those questions sound natural and grammatical; there’s no single "correct way" to phrase the question.